# Connect postgreSQL+postGIS docker container from my local network

Tags: postgresql, docker, ip, postgis, remote-access

I have built a docker container from [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/) with :

```
docker run --name some-postgis -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d mdillon/postgis
docker run -it --link some-postgis:postgres --rm postgres \
    sh -c 'exec psql -h "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR" -p "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT" -U postgres'
```

An inspect :

```
$ docker inspect b89c7f54e76a
[
    {
        "Id": "b89c7f54e76aa82bd142e1eb45a1f12008bf2ee2f94e392b08b386493b58891f",
        "Created": "2017-08-08T14:34:02.375576229Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "postgres"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 8293,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2017-08-09T10:08:11.317833478Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2017-08-08T18:18:17.110547652Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:1c5da6633b90bfb50486b543dd11c7efb800e6d27d338d51aaf82e929d83bde2",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b89c7f54e76aa82bd142e1eb45a1f12008bf2ee2f94e392b08b386493b58891f/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b89c7f54e76aa82bd142e1eb45a1f12008bf2ee2f94e392b08b386493b58891f/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b89c7f54e76aa82bd142e1eb45a1f12008bf2ee2f94e392b08b386493b58891f/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b89c7f54e76aa82bd142e1eb45a1f12008bf2ee2f94e392b08b386493b58891f/b89c7f54e76aa82bd142e1eb45a1f12008bf2ee2f94e392b08b386493b58891f-json.log",
        "Name": "/psql-futurSahel",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": null,
            "Name": "aufs"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "bb59bb5d17ad6b3ca59d7acf5c21936ce19fb15ec9fa13388ce63c01ed559f37",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/bb59bb5d17ad6b3ca59d7acf5c21936ce19fb15ec9fa13388ce63c01ed559f37/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "b89c7f54e76a",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5432/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres",
                "PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.7",
                "LANG=en_US.utf8",
                "PG_MAJOR=9.6",
                "PG_VERSION=9.6.3-1.pgdg80+1",
                "PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data",
                "POSTGIS_MAJOR=2.3",
                "POSTGIS_VERSION=2.3.2+dfsg-1~exp2.pgdg80+1"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "postgres"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "mdillon/postgis",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/postgresql/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "07536f68477b1f345cff2caa3118d7ee9251b0a84a2ef6a1f641c24aecd1ae53",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "5432/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/07536f68477b",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "98ca66036295516d5d653b865f3bf4de976b1f8fc704269ef5d7d067817a8c4d",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "1f95d91f247bb8cb99e8eb5c1d3911b82812947880c9e2ba6ec4db3cdc8f131b",
                    "EndpointID": "98ca66036295516d5d653b865f3bf4de976b1f8fc704269ef5d7d067817a8c4d",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

It works like a charm on my Desktop and I can use psql to interact with the server. It works perfectly!

```
psql -h 172.17.0.2 -p 5432 -U postgres
```

But I would like to allow my colleague to connect the data base, and I don't understand well how it works ...

At this point (if we assume my local IP is `192.168.0.14`)

```
psql -h 192.168.0.14 -p 5432 -U postgres
```

Doesn't work ...

I have found some link like :

- https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/networking-your-docker-containers-using-docker0-bridge/
- http://blog.oddbit.com/2014/08/11/four-ways-to-connect-a-docker/

But it still notes clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is port mapping while running the container.

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 --name some-postgis -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d mdillon/postgis
```

This would map the 5432 (left side) on host to 5432 (right side) on container. Your colleague will be able to access the DB as long as your IP is reachable from his machine

Comment: I have edited my question. `-p 5432:5432` is not equivalent to `-p "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT"` ? If I do `docker run -d -p 5432:5432 postgres` it doesn't create another docker ?

Comment: That command was just as an example. Updated the answer based on the command your posted. `--link` is deprecated now. You should probably use `docker-compose`

Comment: How do you use `docker-compose` ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your colleague can not connect is because you are using the Host-Machine to Docker internal IP Adress, and your colleagues machine does not realize that the 172.17.0.2 address is hosted on your machine.

The correct mechanism is therefore as @Tarun Lalwani mentioned

And now your colleague would connect using your machine i.e. the host of the dockers public ip address.